# how to make multiple models auto migrate in gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-gin

i can see the documentation we do automigrate like this,  `db.AutoMigrate(&model.TheTodo{})`

how about if we have a lot of multiples models? `db.AutoMigrate(&model.TheTodo{}, &model.TheBlog{}, &model.Employee{}, and many more...... )`

will gorm create that table if we put like that? and is that any way to make inside AutoMigrate to make short?

```
db.AutoMigrate(allmodels)
```

would it possible ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option is to nest the structs inside the `AutoMigrate` function:

```
db.AutoMigrate(
    &User{}, 
    &Product{},
    &Order{},
)
```

Or if you want to make the inside "short", you could do:

```
var models = []interface{}{&User{}, &Product{}, &Order{}}

db.Automigrate(models...)
```